# I have a compilation error wanting to upload 3 images at once ( Function name must be a string )

Tags: laravel

I want to upload 3 photos at once in a form with a different name, and when in the controller I am confused, and there is an error, and below this is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pelaku = $request->all();

    $validasi = Validator::make($pelaku, [
        'nik' => 'required|max:16',
        'nama' => 'required',
        'photo_depan' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048s'
    ]);

    $gambar_pelaku = $request->file('photo_depan')('photo_kiri')('photo_kanan');

    $extention = $gambar_pelaku->getClientOriginalExtension();

    if ($request->file('photo_depan')('photo_kiri')('photo_kanan')->isValid()) {

        $namaFoto = "pelaku/" . date('YmdHis') . "." . $extention;

        $upload_path = 'public/uploads/pelaku';

        $request->file('photo_depan')('photo_kiri')('photo_kanan')->move($upload_path, $namaFoto);

        $pelaku['photo_depan']['photo_kiri']['photo_kanan'] = $namaFoto;

    }

    Pelaku::create($pelaku);

    Alert::success('Berhasil di tambah');

    return redirect()->route('pelaku.index');
}
```

I want to upload 3 photos at once in a form with a different name, and when in the controller I am confused, and there is an error, and below this is my controller